# dependency property mode should behave as two way to one way on certain condition

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dependency-properties

I have one custom control which has one dependency property and i am using this custom control as template in datagrid cells. I am having one mainwindow where this datagrid is placed and i have declared one more dependency property to get values from each cell.

For ex:
When any update from custom control of cell 1, will reflect in main window dependency property. Then this dependency property will update all other cells because of two way binding.

But on certain condition, it should behave like one way binding during run time. So i have used **validatevaluecallback** property for validation to behave as oneway or twoway.

But here i have a problem of hitting this validatevaluecallback for all cells when any change occurs on one cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your 2 scenarios.

put your control [settings 1] in CellTemplate

and your control [settings 2] in CellEditingTemplate

of DataGridTemplateColumn.

Then, set the DataGrid's IsReadOnly property with some binding.

that way you can use 2 different bindings on your control, according to situation.